# Storing json as redux state

Tags: json, redux, immutable.js

I'm receiving json data from the backend and I wish to store this data as state in my redux store. Is it always the correct approach to deeply convert this data to Immutable as I do below:

```
reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) 
{
    switch(action.type) 
    {
        case "data_update":
            return Immutable.fromJS(action.data);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I'm working on code where this is done:

```
     case "data_update":
        return Immutable.Map(action.data);
```

Might there be a good reason for doing this? What might this reason be?

Answer (score 0):

Converting the data into `Map` is completely optional! You can choose not to use `Immutable` at all. Since, the core concept of Redux is to store the state and never to mutate it, people started using `Immutable` for freezing the state. If you skip Immutable altogether, it's perfectly okay.

Deeply converting the data into immutable collection prevents us from accidentally mutating the state like this -

```
reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) 
{
    switch(action.type) 
    {
        case "data_update":
            state.users = action.payload;
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that one can do as they like but does it make sense to do a shallow conversion of data into a immutable collection via Immutable.Map. Seems weird to me.

Comment: @Baz We have heavily used Immutable in our product. It makes sense!

Comment: Immutable makes sense but it doesn't make sense as far as I can see to use Immutable.Map on a deeply nested json object since the resulting object won't be immutable.

Comment: @Baz Don't use then.

Answer (score 0):

If "action.data" is a plain object it makes sense to use Immutable.Map() but as you mention if it is a deeply nested object, then I would go for Immutable.fromJS(), otherwise you will have an immutable map but with non immutable properties on it.

This might be a problem if a view receives that mixed object as you will have to access object properties via .get() but then using just dot notation for properties.properties.

Although this approach might not be a problem if you have the convention of having selectors which access the immutable objects but then return to the views always the javascript non-immutable content. Then, that could be a valid solution but in my opinion still quite error prone.